# absolute div comes on container div on small devices

Tags: html, css

I have created a new website based on Bootstrap 3 and I need to place two `div`s (ad banners) outside of the container class.

The first one goes on the left of the page and the second one on right side of the page. Every thing works fine, but I have a small issue on small devices I see the second banner that on the right of page overlaps the container. Here is my CSS code:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
```

And a screenshot of the issue (Desktop vs HTC One X) http://www11.0zz0.com/2016/01/24/04/143938558.png

The website in question is http://eljadida24.com

Comment: where do you want the second banner to be, on small devices ?

Comment: of course, when you make an element absolutely positioned it will "float" out of the grid and be relative to the body (unless you set a parent container with `position:relative`. I see that the website is not responsive and has a fixed width. In that case, I think you need to either remove the viewport meta tag or add the following `<meta name="viewport" content="width=960, initial-scale=1">` change 960 to your site's actual width

Comment: I think there is no problem.

Comment: Please tell us what you want the solution to look like.

Comment: on right side of the page

Answer (score 2):

Your website is not responsive which is a major cause of this problem.

For small devices, I believe you should check ***media query*** to individually arrange different HTML elements for different medias i.e screen sizes.

Also, if you want elements to slide down automatically based on screen size then ***960 grid*** is an option.

And if you want no elements to side down into the next line and just to resize to smaller elements in smaller screens then check [***Responsive web development*** here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)
In responsive you need to convert all the elements with size measured in pixels 'px' to percent '%'. For the same website conversion of 'px' to '%' can be done using [this website.](http://rqrwd.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8gwn61k/)

Replace the `width` of the banners and content area and you're set. Neither banner will overlap the content area at any width.